# Capture keyboard events while mouse is captured but window not focused (Win32)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm implementing a custom control that can initiate drag events. I initiate a drag when the user presses the left mouse button by processing `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and calling `SetCapture()`. This causes all mouse events, even those outside my control's client area, to be sent to it, exactly as I want.

I would also like to be able to capture key presses so I can cancel the drag if the user presses the ESC key (`VK_ESCAPE`). Since my control doesn't have the keyboard focus (and I don't want it to steal the focus away from the control that has it), I can't listen to `WM_KEYDOWN`. For other reasons too complicated to explain, I also would prefer not to use the  [`DragDetect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

How can my control find out about ESC key presses while the drag is ongoing?

Comment: Short of using a global keyboard hook, I don't think you can.

Comment: `WM_KEYDOWN` messages will come into your message loop no matter which control in your app has the focus, so you can test for them directly and abort the drag when you see an escape key.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it's this easy:

```
// message loop...
switch (msg)
{
    // ...

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        // do some stuff
        RegisterHotKey(hwnd, 0 /* id */, 0, VK_ESCAPE);
        // do some more stuff
        break;

    // ... 

    case WM_HOTKEY:
        if (VK_ESCAPE == HIWORD(lParam) &&
            IDHOT_SNAPDESKTOP != wParam &&
            IDHOT_SNAPWINDOW != wParam)
            {
            // handle ESC keypress
            UnregisterHotKey(hwnd, 0 /* id */);
            }
        break;

    // ...

}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution. `RegisterHotKey` is a global function that can mess with other applications. Like was suggested by @JonathanPotter in the comments above, keep processing keyboard messages. You'll be receiving either `WM_KEYDOWN` or `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` for key presses.